# Error in cross compilation in case of using new and delete

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling

I would like to run my C++ code on a ChibiOS, I can compile and link the code if I'm replacing the `new` `delete` with the C functions malloc and free. But I still would like to fix the issue. When I'm using `new` `delete` I'm receiving the following error:

```
no memory region specified for loadable section `.ARM.extab'
```

This is the linking script

```
    /*
 * BCM2835 memory setup.
 */
__und_stack_size__  = 0x0004;
__abt_stack_size__  = 0x0004;
__fiq_stack_size__  = 0x0010;
__irq_stack_size__  = 0x0080;
__svc_stack_size__  = 0x0004;
__sys_stack_size__  = 0x0400;
__stacks_total_size__   = __und_stack_size__ + __abt_stack_size__ + __fiq_stack_size__ + __irq_stack_size__ + __svc_stack_size__ + __sys_stack_size__;

MEMORY
{
     ram : org = 0x8000, len = 0x06000000 - 0x10021 
     extabram : org = 0x06008000 - 0x10020, len = 0x10000 - 0x20
}

__ram_start__       = ORIGIN(ram);
__ram_size__        = LENGTH(ram);
__ram_end__     = __ram_start__ + __ram_size__;

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0;

    .text : ALIGN(16) SUBALIGN(16)
    {
        _text = .;
        KEEP(*(vectors))
        *(.text)
        *(.text.*)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rodata.*)
        *(.glue_7t)
        *(.glue_7)
        *(.gcc*)
        *(.ctors)
        *(.dtors)
    } > ram

    .ARM.extab : {*(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)} > extabram

    __exidx_start = .;
    .ARM.exidx : {*(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)} > ram
    __exidx_end = .;

    .eh_frame_hdr : {*(.eh_frame_hdr)}

    .eh_frame : ONLY_IF_RO {*(.eh_frame)}

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;
    _textdata = _etext;

    .data :
    {
        _data = .;
        *(.data)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.data.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.ramtext)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _edata = .;
    } > ram 

    .bss :
    {
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(.bss.*)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        *(COMMON)
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss_end = .;
    } > ram    
}

PROVIDE(end = .);
_end = .;

__heap_base__              = _end;
__heap_end__               = __ram_end__ - __stacks_total_size__;
__main_thread_stack_base__ = __ram_end__ - __stacks_total_size__;
```

what does it missing in the linker script?

---

**EDITED**
After I followed Chris Desjardins answer, I'm receiving the following errors:

```
 Linking build/ch.elf
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-abort.o): In function `abort':
    abort.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `_exit'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-fstatr.o): In function `_fstat_r':
    fstatr.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_fstat'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-sbrkr.o): In function `_sbrk_r':
    sbrkr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_sbrk'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_kill_r':
    signalr.c:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `_kill'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-signalr.o): In function `_getpid_r':
    signalr.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `_getpid'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-writer.o): In function `_write_r':
    writer.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_write'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-closer.o): In function `_close_r':
    closer.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_close'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-isattyr.o): In function `_isatty_r':
    isattyr.c:(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `_isatty'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-lseekr.o): In function `_lseek_r':
    lseekr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_lseek'
    /home/robu/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_Lite_for_ARM_EABI/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/4.7.2/../../../../arm-none-eabi/lib/libc.a(lib_a-readr.o): In function `_read_r':
    readr.c:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `_read'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make: *** [build/ch.elf] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the ARM.extab section doesn't have a place in memory. In this example they put it in flash.

http://hertaville.com/2012/06/29/a-sample-linker-script/

But you should be ok just carving out some ram for it as follows:

```
MEMORY
{
    ram : org = 0x8000, len = 0x06000000 - 0x10021 
    extabram : org = 0x06008000 - 0x10020, len = 0x10000 - 0x20
}
```

Then put the ARM.extab section in the new ram region:

```
.ARM.extab : {*(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)} > extabram
```

You could also just try to put it into the normal ram section...

```
.ARM.extab : {*(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)} > ram
```

Comment: I tried this option, but I'm getting a really long error messages, see my question for the details.

Comment: Have you tried the alternative of just going to > ram? without the mods to the MEMORY section.

Comment: Looks a lot like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493122/missing-something-in-arm-g

and this:  http://sourceware.org/ml/newlib/2011/msg00648.html

Comment: It seems that you are linking with libc, but you want to link with libg instead

Comment: Can I assume you also removed the link with libc?

Comment: Here is the command: `arm-none-eabi-gcc ... objects.o .. -mcpu=arm1176jzf-s -nostartfiles -T../../os/ports/GCC/ARM/BCM2835/ld/BCM2835.ld -Wl,-Map=build/ch.map,--cref,--no-warn-mismatch,--gc-sections  -mno-thumb-interwork -lg   -o build/ch.elf`

Comment: Why are you linking with gcc rather than g++?

Comment: Finally I found the solution here:http://forum.chibios.org/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=783&p=7792#p7792

Answer (score 0):

.ARM.extab section is created when exception support is required.

One of the differences between `malloc` and `new` is that new cannot return NULL: it must throw an exception in the event of memory allocation failure.

Would compiling with [--force_new_nothrow](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armccref/armccref_CIHEEGJF.htm) option help?

Comment: in this case I'm receiving the following error: `arm-none-eabi-g++: error: unrecognized command line option '--force_new_nothrow'` but I'm compiling with the following flags: -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions

Comment: Yes, it's an armcc option. Looks like there's no equivalent option in g++. An option is to replace instances of `new` with `new (nothrow)`.